# Access wordpress from another mac on LAN with vhost

Tags: wordpress, apache, lan, vhosts

Please show me the httpd.conf in apache 2.2, hosts file, and any wordpress config if it needs, to access the wordpress site from another machine on local area network using virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

you can access directly via the IP. If you need to access via a domain name (given in wordpress), you can edit the /private/etc/hosts with the ip of the machine you would like to access and the domainname.